# ScalaObservable.foreach doesn't block?

Tags: mongodb-scala

In the [MongoDB Scala driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/), `ScalaObservable.foreach` doesn't block as I expected.  Since it returns Unit I can't use `.toFuture` it to wait either.

What's the way idiomatic way to wait?  My program is quitting too early.

As a workaround I've replaced `.foreach` with a `.map(f).toFuture` where `f: _ => Unit`, then blocking on the future.